# A graded abelian group and a graded map

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have an elementary question about a graded abelian group and a graded map. Here is the situation.

> Let $A$ be a free abelian group of rank $2$ spanned by $1$ and $x$. Let us make $A$ be a graded abelian group by assigning degree $-1$ to $1$ and degree $1$ to $x$.
>   We define a multiplication map $m: A \otimes A \to A$ as follows:
>   $m(1\otimes1)=1, m(1\otimes x)=m(x\otimes 1)=x, m(x \otimes x)=0$.
>   Then $m$ is a graded map of degree $1$.

I am confused how the grading works with this map $m$.
Since $m$ has degree $1$, it sends an element of degree $n$ to an element of degree $n+1$, right?

Since $1$ has degree $-1$, the element $1\otimes 1$ has degree $-2$ and it is mapped to $1 \in A$, which has degree $1$ so it is ok.

Since $x$ has degree $1$ so $1 \otimes x$ has degree $0$ and it is mapped to $x$ , which has degree $1$. So it is ok.

We know $A$ is a direct product of two subgroups generated by $1$ and $x$. So every element is either of degree $-1$ or $1$, isn't it? Is the element $0\in A$ of degree $0$?

Another question is about the map $m(x \otimes x)=0$.
The element $x \otimes x$ has degree $2$ but the element $0\in A$ is not of degree $3$ right? Then why the degree of the map $m$ is $1$?

Could someone clarify these?

Comment: You have to use the definitions: That $A$ is a $(\mathbb{Z})$-graded abelian group means $A=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}A_n$ with abelian groups $A_n$. In your example you set $A_{-1}=\mathbb{Z},\; A_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ and $A_n=0$ if $n\neq -1,1$. Hence $m(x\otimes x)=0\in A_3$.

Comment: @Ralph Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

The grading is given here with respect to the *multiplicative* (!) group $\{+1,-1\}$. Since $1$ is the neutral element of this group, by "graded map of degree $1$" we simply mean a graded map. This already answers all of your questions:

1) There is no element of degree $0$. The zero belongs both to degrees $+1$ and $-1$, and is in fact the only such element.

2) $1 \otimes 1$ and $x \otimes x$ have degree $1$, and are mapped to $1$ and $0$, which have both degree $1$. Besides, $1 \otimes x$ and $x \otimes 1$ have degree $-1$, which are mapped to $x$, which has degree $-1$. Thus, $m$ is graded.

By the way, one can construct $m$ more elegantly as follows: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded. It follows that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$- or $\{+1,-1\}$-graded. Now $A$ is isomorphic to its underlying abelian group. Hence, $A$ becomes a graded commutative ring in such a way that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ as a graded commutative ring.

Comment: "Graded abelian group" without further specification usually means $\mathbb{Z}$-graded. As such $1\otimes 1$ has degree -2.

Comment: Well, both interpretations work. I think $\{\pm 1\}$ is more natural here.

Comment: I can't help, but to my understanding of such a forum, the questioner defines the setting. And in the question above, the OP mentions degrees -2, 3 and obviously adds the degrees. So I find it rather strange, to state "The grading is given here with respect to the multiplicative (!) group $\{+1,−1\}$."  At least there no support at all for your interpretation in the text of the question.